# What's a good database stack for hosting online books?

Tags: database

I want to be able to request specific pages at a time, and be able to quickly go to previous and next pages of a single book. Lots of read requests. Not nearly as many writes.

Should I go for a NoSQL database? What choice would be good and what are the advantages for my use case?

There's just so many choices nowadays: MongoDB, AWS DocumentDB, AWS DynamoDB, AWS RDS, Google Cloud Firebase I'm a little overwhelmed.

Comment: If you give me more info I will reply better. Is this a project or do you already have an application up and running? Are you already on the cloud or not? Do you already have users or not?

Comment: How many books, a thousand or a million? Book data is text or images?

Comment: Please let us know and we will reopen the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It depends by one factor:

- **If the pages are text:** go for a RDBMS database like SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc..
- **If the pages are images:** go for a NoSQL database like MongoDB, etc..

Then choose a cloud that has something specific that you really need at all costs that other clouds don't have.
If you don't need any in specific all the clouds are the same for you.